# how to simulate 3dmax cellular map for displace like in video?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

found a very cool way to make nice rocks
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0XQVS1qxZI
here a guy uses 3dmax with displacement with cellular map.
tried using voronoi in such a way, but i get wrong results. don't know what am i doing wrong here.
[image]

Please advice how to achieve this:

[image]

is it even possible to do in blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure is possible. I made a similar rock in a few minutes. You can check my settings from the image.

[image: rocks from displacement]

You can do this with one displacement map but for some reason I got better results with two. Put them underneath a subdivision surface modifier, and the displacement modifiers should have their strength reduced to the same number (.3-.5). The realism of the rocks comes from playing with the voronoi texture settings: size, and distance metric were most important. I found distance squared worked best. Also the color ramp can help level off any circular spots in the texture.

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: thank you! i understood my mistake! i was making the rock from already subdivided icosphere! and this method need low-res icosphere (howhere in video it seems to me that he uses a very smooth one)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad you figured it out!